# Solving the equation $\exp{y\left(x\right)} + y\left(x\right) + 1 = 0$ to find the function $y$

Tags: functional-equations

I am trying to solve the following equation and find a real-valued function $y\left(x\right)$ which satisfies

$$
\exp{y\left(x\right)} + y\left(x\right) + 1 = 0, \hspace{0.2cm}\forall x>0
$$

The trivial solution $y\left(x\right) = x_0$ where $x_0$ is the root of
$$
\exp{x} + x + 1 = 0
$$
is probably one solution. Is there any way to find a non-trivial one? Any ideas?

Comment: Since $y(x)$ is effectively the variable, this problem is equivalent to finding the solutions to $\exp x + x + 1$, so you're not likely to find any more...

Answer (score 4):

There is certainly at least no *differentiable* solution. If we differentiate both sides, we get $y'(x)\exp(y(x)) + y'(x) = 0$, or $y'(x)(\exp(y(x)) + 1 = 0)$. Since $\exp(y(x))+1$ is never zero, this implies that $y'(x) = 0$, so that $y(x)$ is a constant, and hence $y(x) = x_0$ where $x_0$ is as you specified.

This reasoning shows that there cannot be a solution that is differentiable on any interval of $\mathbb{R}^+$. Maybe there's crazy function that does work, but there probably isn't a solution that you can write down nicely.

Answer (score 4):

No matter that you have marked it as $y(x)$, the solution will be the same as

$$e^x+x+1=0$$

In order $y(x)$ to be a function $x$ must show up elsewhere not just within $y(x)$. Otherwise $y(x)$ has no different meaning than any other symbols you could use $H,u,p,g(x),d...$

Therefore there is no other solution than within reals

$$y(x)=-W(\frac1{e})-1$$

where $W(x)$ is Lambert W-function

or if you take a continuation of W-function it would be

$$y(x)=-W_n(\frac1{e})-1$$

but either way it can be just a constant.